# Referencing an object within a collection of collections by key

Tags: vba

Firstly, apologies, this is my first post thus I may not have used best practice.

I'm writing an application using VBA for Excel.

I have created a Class, and then instatiated several objects of that Class and added them to a Collection. I have then added that Collection to another Collection, and repeated the process so that I end up with a Collection of Collections of objects of the same Class, like a hierarchy I suppose.

Whenever I add to a Collection I create a key to uniquely identify the thing that I am adding. I now want to use the key to reference specific objects within the "hierarchy".

The following pseudo hopefully explains the process of instatiating the object, adding to a new Collection, then adding the Collection to a new Collection (note for simplicity I have only added a single object thereby resulting in a single branch hierarchy, whereas my actual code adds multiple objects to multiple Collections).

```
Public Element As CElement
Public InsideCollection As Collection
Public OutsideCollection As Collection

Sub Main()

    Set Element = New CElement
    Set InsideCollection = New Collection
    Set OutsideCollection = New Collection

    Element.Field1 = "blah1"
    Element.Field2 = "blah2"

    InsideCollection.Add Element, Element.Field1

    OutsideCollection.Add InsideCollection, "ABCD"

End Sub
```

Now that I have loaded this data into a kind of hierarchy structure, how do I gain access to specific elements at the lowest level without looping through all elements searching for the right one? I'd have thought I could do something along the lines of:

```
OutsideCollection("ABCD").InsideCollection("blah1").Field2
```

or

```
OutsideCollection.InsideCollection("blah1").Field2
```

but they give this error:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I've also tried the above with referencing the element by integer value eg.

```
OutsideCollection(1).InsideCollection(1).Field2
```

but get the same error.

Any ideas?

Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Long way.** Let us define two additional variables `innerCol` and `innerEl`:

```
Dim innerCol As Collection
Dim innerEl As CElement
```

and then get value of `OutsideCollection` collection by key:

```
Set innerCol = OutsideCollection("ABCD")
```

Now `innerCol` contains collection of `CElements`. Let us get single element by key:

```
Set innerEl = innerCol("blah1")
```

Variable `innerEl` contains object of type `CElement` and we can get its properties:

```
MsgBox innerEl.Field1 ' returns "blah1"
MsgBox innerEl.Field2 ' returns "blah2"
```

**Short way**, without additional variables we could use this one:

```
MsgBox OutsideCollection("ABCD")("blah1").Field1 ' returns "blah1"
MsgBox OutsideCollection("ABCD")("blah1").Field2 ' returns "blah2"
```

Answer (score 0):

To access object by a literal there is "!" operator:

```
Sub test_collection_intf()
  Dim v_a As New Collection
  v_a.Add Item:=New Collection, Key:="first"
  v_a!first.Add Item:=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"), Key:="red"
  v_a!first!red!Type = "color"

  v_a.Add Item:=New Collection, Key:="second"
  v_a!Second.Add Item:=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"), Key:="green"
  v_a!Second!green!scheme = "RGBA"

  Debug.Print "Access by literals"
  Debug.Print "v_a!first!red.Count:"; v_a!first!red.Count; "v_a!first!red!type: "; v_a!first!red!Type
  Debug.Print "v_a!Second!green.Count"; v_a!Second!green.Count; "v_a!Second!green!RGBA: "; v_a!first!red!RGBA
  Debug.Print "v_a!Second!green!scheme: "; v_a!Second!green!scheme
' But it is impossiable to use a variable to acces field of object as in Perl
'  Dim v_key_l1 As String, v_key_l2 As String
'  v_key_l1 = "first": v_key_l2 = "red"
'  Debug.Print "v_a!v_key_l1!v_key_l2:"; v_a; !v_key_l1; !v_key_l2
'  v_key_l1 = "second": v_key_l2 = "green"
'  Debug.Print "v_a!v_key_l1!v_key_l2:"; v_a!v_key_l1!v_key_l2
End Sub
```

Output in Immediate window:

```
Access by literals
v_a!first!red.Count: 1 v_a!first!red!type: color
v_a!Second!green.Count 1 v_a!Second!green!RGBA: 
v_a!Second!green!scheme: RGBA
```