# Get a object inside a collection using key VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oop, collections

I have the following structure in my VBA Project:
An object of `assetSharing` class is instanciated inside an object `Asset` in a **`Collection`** because I have more than one share inside an asset.

> **Class Modules**
>
> Asset
>
> assetSharing

```vb
'Class Asset
Public price As Double
Public name As String
Public sharing As Collection

Sub initialValues(price as Double, name As String)
    Me.price = price
    Me.name = name
End Sub
```

```vb
'Class assetSharing
Public shareFrom As String
Public shareTo As String

Sub initialValues(shareFrom as String, shareTo As String)
    Me.shareFrom = shareFrom 
    Me.shareTo = shareTo 
End Sub
```

Here the code where I create the Assets and their Sharing inside a Collection using a **KEY** *MyKey-XPTO*:

```vb
Public myAsset as Asset

Public Sub newAsset()
    myAsset.initialValues 182.63, "XPTO"
    myAsset.sharing.Add New assetSharing, "MyKey-XPTO"
    
    'Now I need to find this sharing inside the collection using the key 
    'to assign the values shareFrom and shareTo
    myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareFrom = "John Doe"
    myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareTo = "Mary Jane"

End Sub
```

This piece of code didn't work to find the sharing, how can I manage it, please?

```
myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareFrom = "John Doe"
myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareTo = "Mary Jane"
```

I tried to follow this instruction, but it is quite different from my situation and I am not managing to adapt the code:
[Referencing an object within a collection of collections by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498004/referencing-an-object-within-a-collection-of-collections-by-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup by key is working fine so there is something else:

- `Asset` class:

  ```
  Public price As Double
  Public name As String
  Public sharing As New Collection

  Sub initialValues(price As Double, name As String)
      Me.price = price
      Me.name = name
  End Sub
  ```
- `assetSharing` class:

  ```
  Public shareFrom As String
  Public shareTo As String

  Sub initialValues(shareFrom As String, shareTo As String)
      Me.shareFrom = shareFrom
      Me.shareTo = shareTo
  End Sub
  ```
- `newAsset` sub:

  ```
  Public myAsset As Asset

  Public Sub newAsset()
      Set myAsset = New Asset
      myAsset.initialValues 182.63, "XPTO"
      myAsset.sharing.Add New assetSharing, "MyKey-XPTO"

      myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareFrom = "John Doe"
      myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareTo = "Mary Jane"
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I don't know what was wrong but now everything works well! tks

Comment: Glad to hear that all is OK now, so to mark the issue as closed you can accept the answer you think fits best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone more versed with classes will chip in. I would appreciate feedback as a learning point for me.

I would expect to see getters and setters as well as instantiation. The former points aside the following changes I think might be required.

```
Option Explicit

Public myAsset As Asset
Public aSharing As assetSharing '<== Additional declaration

Public Sub newAsset()
    Set myAsset = New Asset  '< instantiate instances of class
    Set aSharing = New assetSharing  '< instantiate instances of class
    myAsset.initialValues 182.63, "XPTO" 'remove ()
    myAsset.sharing.Add aSharing, "MyKey-XPTO"
    myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareFrom = "John Doe"
    myAsset.sharing("MyKey-XPTO").shareTo = "Mary Jane"

End Sub
```

and

cls ASSET

```
Option Explicit

Public price As Double
Public name As String
Public sharing As Collection

Sub initialValues(price As Double, name As String)
    Me.price = price
    Me.name = name
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sharing = New Collection   '<have collection instantiated
End Sub
```